# Issue using redux variables via redux call inside react-apollo graphql with apollo compose

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-apollo

My Component needs to call an graphql query but it needs variables which can be only used by redux. So I have mapped the redux's connect to react apollo compose. But I have issues getting the data from reducer and the call is not loading properly.

```
class abc extends Component {
   componentWillMount() {
     console.log(this.props.variableData); // Getting empty object.
   }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ variableDataFetchAction }, dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
     variableData: state.reducerName.variableData,
  }
}

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
  graphql(MyQuery, {
    options: props => {
      return {
        .....,
        variables: props.variableData,
      };
    },
  }),
)(abc);
```

I need to know whether there is problem in the way in which I can redux. Because my store seems to empty.

Comment: I suppose you mixed the connect and compose

Comment: I am using compose from react-apollo and using redux connect inside compose so that it will execute first and then load query data.

Comment: All right. Would you mind specify your code with https://codesandbox.io or sth like that

Comment: It seems that there is a redundant right parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, you don't need `react-apollo` to call a GraphQL api endpoint.

In your case, you're utilizing 2 library that handle it's own store (assuming you're using `Apollo Client 2`). Redux has it's `Redux Store` and Apollo is using `InMemoryCache` for caching.

Stuff you fetched via `graphql` are stored in Apollo cache, you can use `Apollo Client Developer Tools` Chrome extensions to inspect it's content.

If you want to put the data fetch via `apollo-client` back to Redux store, you have to manually dispatch an action to do it (once the `data` return from `graphql` calls). This is mostly undocumented since it's not recommended to use 2 types of `Store`.

If all you need is to call a GraphQL endpoint and not changing your Redux implementation. I suggest using [apollo-fetch](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-fetch) or [graphql-request](https://github.com/prismagraphql/graphql-request) instead.